# Asymptotics of $\sum_{i=1}^{n^2 - 1} \frac{i^2}{[\frac{n^3}{3}]^2}$

Tags: asymptotics

I need to somehow figure out what happens with the following sum:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n^2 - 1} \frac{i^2}{[\frac{n^3}{3}]^2}$$

when $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Should it be zero? Should it be a constant?

If I try and guess that sum of squares from $1$ to $n$ is not more than $n^3%$, it follows that a sum of squares from $1$ to $n^2 - 1$ is not more than $n^6$ (**am I right with that?**), but that gives me the same asymptotic order in the numerator is the same as in the denominator.

So I am in doubt if this is the right upper bound, maybe it's really less than $n^6$, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [the formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number)
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N} i^2 = \frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6},
$$
your sum can be written as
$$
\frac{1}{[\frac{n^3}{3}]^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n^2-1} i^2 = \frac{1}{[\frac{n^3}{3}]^2} \cdot \frac{(n^2-1)n^2(2n^2-1)}{6}.
$$
It's not clear whether the denominator means $\frac{n^3}{3}$ or $\lfloor \frac{n^3}{3} \rfloor$ (these are the possibilities that come immediately to my mind). In either case<sup>1</sup>, for large $n$, the limit of the above function is the same as the limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{3}{n^3} \right)^2 \cdot \frac{(n^2-1)n^2(2n^2-1)}{6}.
$$
I presume you know how to evaluate this limit.

---

<sup>1</sup>*EDIT:* Here's the proof for the $\lfloor \frac{n^3}{3} \rfloor$ case. Our claim is essentially that as $x \to \infty$, the quantity $\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x}$ approaches $1$. To see this, note that 
$$
\frac{x - 1}{x} \leq \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x} \leq 1
$$
and apply the squeeze (sandwich) theorem.

Comment: Thank you so much!
But could you please also explain why we can throw out the integer part for large $n$ and guarantee that the limits will be the same?

It should be true if the limit of $\frac{x}{[x]}$ is 1 when $x \rightarrow \infty$, but the latter is not that obvious for me...

Comment: @wh1t3cat1k Added the proof for that claim.

Comment: Thank you very much. This will surely help me.